# How to do image auto zoom in, animation and zoom out using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am dealing with Jquery animation which Include image zoom in,pause,give animation and zoom out. How to do that? I want my image zoom in then pause some seconds and during that pause seconds, I want to apply my animation and after finishing my animation, I want to zoom out. How to do that?? My code as follows:

```
<div class="home2 container-fluid">
   <h3 class="title">Safety</h3>
   <p class="des"> HI </p>  
</div>
```

My CSS as follows:

```
@keyframes breath {
    0%   { background-size: 100% 100%; }
    50% { background-size: 120% 120%; }
    100% { background-size: 100% 100%; }
}
.home2 {

   background-image:url("../img/sofa2.jpg");
   background-size:100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   height:100vh;
   width:100%;
   animation: breath 7s linear infinite;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

Currently it only works with zoom in and zoom out
Please help me to do this..!!THANKS in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes breath {
  0% { transform: scale(0); }
  50% { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(0); }
}
```

maybe you need this?

**Add, use `transfrom` & `transition`:**

```
.home2 {
  background-image:url("../img/sofa2.jpg");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  transition: 3.5s all linear;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.home2.zoom {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

1. `.home2` addClass `zoom` it begin `zoom in`
2. remove class `zoom` it begin `zoom out`

Comment: No, I want to give my animation in between zoom in and zoom out

Comment: @Maulik I changed my answer, you can try this. Maybe I misunderstand `zoom in` or `zoom out` ?

Comment: That is ok but now when zoom in occurs, I want to apply pause and give my animation and then I want to zoom out. How to do that??

Comment: To get this, I recommend not to use `animation`, try to use `transition` & `transfrom` and class to do this. Wait moment, I change my answer to tell you.